# The difference between the 400 and 404 HTTP errors

Tags: http, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-400

What the difference between the 400 and 404 HTTP errors?
Can you show me an example for understand the difference?

Thank you.

Comment: This is server about coding.  Where is your code?  what do you want to do?

Comment: There’s a description there for both in pretty plain English ... You’d have to start with telling us what specifically about that you don’t understand, if you require more explanation ...

Comment: Is it still unclear?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The 404 represent resource not exist. i.e The called API dose not exist or Request Page dose not exist. But in case 400 the resource exist but input is wrong.

```
404
http://example.com/pageNotExist.html


400
http://example.com/Api/getCustomer/email@xyz.com
//here email is wrong or not exist
```